# Jquery Plugins in React using Browserify

Tags: reactjs, jquery-plugins

I am building a react component that requires [Devbridge's Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) `jQuery` plugin. The problem is how to load the plugin via `npm`. I already used [this suggestion](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/112064849860/using-jquery-plugins-with-npm) as seen:

```
import React from 'react';
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('autocomplete');

class Search extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    let id = this.props.clientId;
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
          serviceUrl: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=${id}`,
          onSelect: function (suggestion) {
              // this.props.handleSearch(suggestion);
              console.log(suggestion);
          }
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <input type="text" name="tracks" id="autocomplete"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search
```

...and have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
      "autocomplete": "./node_modules/devbridge-autocomplete/dist/jquery.autocomplete.js"
    }
```

...but  I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the `jquery-ui.js` to load the autocomplete box I have just load that js and implemented below code

```
 var Parent=React.createClass({
  componentDidMount:function()
  {
        var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
   $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
     source: availableTags
   });
  },
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>

        <input type="text" name="tracks" id="autocomplete" placeholder="enter text start from any coding language " style={{"width":"400px;"}}/>
      </div>
      )
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rduLy0MUi33VkuPlR7TX?p=preview)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I am using browserify here, therefore my packages are loaded via npm and not with the script tag so they can be bundled. Secondly, I am not using jquery-ui's autocomplete but [devbridge's](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

Comment: @Chris: ohh but what you have used it's for Jquery why you used it for React you have to use something else which is React component like https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete

Comment: Nice. Thanks for pointing me to that but I will appreciate if my question is actually answered.